# Parameter from android not recognized in API

Tags: android

**Goal**

I am writing a program where a user's input is taken as a parameter and queried against an online API.

**Problem**

Oddly, I cannot get my parameter into my API successfully. The error I get is
"Could not look up user information; You have an error in your SQL syntax;" Which as it says plainly , is an SQL error. Therefore I was thinking there was a problem in passing my parameter since the application works when I hard code parameter and say `"select name from table where id=1"`.

This is the parameter code and despite many edits and changes I got the same issue which caused me to look to my php even if everything works right in the browser.

```
 HttpParams param = new BasicHttpParams();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> inputArguments = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                inputArguments.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", idnum));
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(param);
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com/DAIIS/getName.php");
                request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(inputArguments, "UTF-8"));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);
```

**Where I think the problem lie**

I belives the problem lies in my select statement

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
//Connect to DB
include ("dbcon.php");
 //Run query
$para=$_GET['id'];
$sql=("SELECT name FROM class where stu_id=$para");
```

I say this because after stripping my API to the bare minimum the program's error was `Could not look up user information; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`
but if i hard code the parameter (it works) or put something random like `stu_id=$_GET['id'];` it returns blank.

So is the way that I used this parameter incorrect for android? even if it works in the browser?

Thank you

Comment: Are you encoding the string data you send?

Comment: @Kelevandos well in my code snippet has all i do.Missing something?

Comment: try changing `$_GET` to `$_POST`...

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi I changed Get to POST and wrapped the id in " "and it worked. however, I am now getting the same error in my browser that I was getting in my app. Could you explain why? App works but I liked the browser for easy testing.

Comment: Yes it is simple , you are using `HttpPost` so its a `POST` method call, and so in such case you can not get data using `$_GET`, hope you got it ?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Got it, please post an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked for :

Just change '$_GET'  to '$_POST',

As a side note

You can also check 'POST' request in browser, in order to do that add 'Rest client plugin' to your browser and you are done and have fun with api calls :)